# How to get ajax accordion selected index from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I have used Ajax accordion. what I need is to get current selected index when I click on accordion tab that is on billing information I should get selectedindex=0 in Javascript or in jquery
[image]

I have set javascript as

**Note : billing information is a class which is set in OPCPanels**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {

        $(".billinginformation").click(function (event, ui) {
            alert("hi");

            alert($(".billinginformation").accordion("option", "active"))                
        });
    }
</script>
```

HTML code

```
 <ajax:Accordion ID="OPCPanels" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="widget billinginformation" ContentCssClass="content" AutoSize="None">
        <Panes>
        <ajax:AccordionPane ID="BillingInformation" runat="server" CssClass="widget">
            <Header><h2>Billing Information</h2></Header>
            <Content>HI</Content>
        </ajax:AccordionPane>
        <ajax:AccordionPane ID="ShippingInformation" runat="server" CssClass="widget">
            <Header>Shipping Information</Header>
            <Content>hello</content>
        </ajax:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
</ajax:Accordion>
```

I have set billinginformation class to my main accordion and on click of any accordion I get the alert of "hi".

**but how should I get that which selected Index I have selected in JavaScript?**

Comment: Can u share a example of accordion please?

Comment: shared, layout is not proper

Comment: try `alert($(".billinginformation").index();)`

Comment: @yezzz on any selection I am getting answer as 1

Comment: wait I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the example code (*and the source*) at http://www.newschool.edu/ajax/Accordion/Accordion.aspx, you need to use

```
var behavior = $find("<%=OPCPanels.ClientID%>_AccordionExtender");
alert( behavior.get_SelectedIndex() );
```

---

*you can view the actual source code to make sure what the `id` of the accordion extender element is.*

Comment: Gettinh null in both the case  var behavior = $find('OPCPanels_AccordionExtender'); // this could be $find('OPCPanels_AccordionExtender');
                alert(behavior);

Comment: @Xtremcool you need to see the actual source code of the rendered page to see what is the `id` that gets assigned from .net

Comment: I am getting my actual id by   var behavior = document.getElementById("<%=OPCPanels.ClientID%>");
                alert(behavior);. But not able to resolve the issue for 'get_SelectedIndex

Comment: Try with  `$find("<%=OPCPanels.ClientID%>_AccordionExtender")`

Comment: Getting null on defining this

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit accordion.  Try:

```
$find('OPCPanels').get_SelectedIndex()
```

EDIT:

There's not much documentation left around on the AJAX toolkit.  See what you can scrounge from these links.

[Accordion SelectedIndex behind code of last item selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188488/accordion-selectedindex-behind-code-of-last-item-selected)
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=215

Comment: Its giving error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_SelectedIndex' of null

Comment: See my edits.  Code examples for webforms are scant these days.

Comment: getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_SelectedIndex' of null

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that html actually looks like in the browser, so I've chosen to use click on element with widget class: EDIT: now using CssClass

```
$('#OPCPanels [CssClass="widget"]').click(function (event, ui) {
     alert("Index: " + $(this).index() );
});
```

Comment: Its not going in click event\

Comment: This click event is not being called.
but whats the issue if I m calling  $(".billinginformation").click(function (event, ui) {} . This click event is working well . I need slected Index

Comment: If the original click handler was called, then so should this one. You did put the code inside your pageLoad function? Here's a demo showing my click handler works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/oxke4aup/

Comment: I had tried but was not working. Thanks for the effort